# MariaDB: ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away

Tags: linux, mysql, mysql-connection

When i try to execute a query i got error:

```
  MariaDB [suitecrm]> select *   from waiter_log;
    ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
    No connection. Trying to reconnect...
```

An error does not occur every time:

```
MariaDB [suitecrm]> select count(*) from waiter_log;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    64418348
Current database: suitecrm

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      893 |
+----------+
1 row in set (2.13 sec)

MariaDB [suitecrm]> select count(*) from waiter_log; 
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      893 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

***/etc/my.cnf***

```
max_allowed_packet = 128M
interactive_timeout=20
wait_timeout=20
```

Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.64-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: what do you get with select count(*) from waiter_log; ?

Comment: darxmurf , i edited my question

Comment: do you get the gone away right after you launch the query or is there a delay ?

Comment: No error if right now , when pause more than 20 sec i get error.

Comment: Yep but then it reconnects automatically isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is. it turns out this is a normal situation